# Go postgres connection SSL not enabled

Tags: postgresql, ssl, go

I'm trying to connect to my localhost postgresql server without SSL and I'm getting this error:

```
pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
```

That's fine, I know how to fix it:

```
type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB     *sql.DB
}

func (a *App) Initialize(dbname string) {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("dbname=%s sslmode=disable", dbname)
    var err error
    a.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer a.DB.Close()
}
```

However I'm still getting the error!

Comment: There are other syntaxes too to connect to a postgres db using golang, did you tried any other ways ?

Comment: @zenwraight yeah, I ended up going with the URL string version to get the initial stuff to work, but I need to be able to change the database name on the fly for testing `a.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", "postgresql://localhost:5432/bookstore?sslmode=disable")`

Comment: Ya I was going to suggest this one only, because I had also come across the same error and then ended up using this above string only

Comment: You `go` code looks correct to me. I had a similar code as well but was unable to replicate your problem. Just wondering what `postgres` version you're on?  I tried it on 9.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to recreate your error with a fresh install of postgres. While the error output was

`pq: SSL is not enabled on the server`

the real error was not having any databases created. To create a testdb let's run

`createdb testdb`

in your terminal with postgres already running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer comes more just to assign a parameter flag to your Postgres connection string url.

I was connecting to an AWS RDS by URL and I've just change to localhost on `5432` default port.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5432?sslmode=disable
```

or

```
http://localhost:5432?sslmode=disable
```

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon this trying to connect to Postgresql server from my Go program with wrong password.